# concrete example for Promises and nodejs (and no solution)

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, bluebird

So I'd like to learn more about Promises (I arbitrarily chose Bluebird, despite the 'succinct' documentation) by attempting to implement a common use case, using nodejs:

I have a bunch of some 9000 or so URLs in a file, with some empty lines as well. I would like to:

- FILTER out empty lines (url.length <= 0)
- FILTER out those that no longer respond (via a HEAD request using the `request` module)
- MAP to get an IPv4 address via `dns.resolve()`
- MAP use that IPv4 address and http://ipinfo.io/xx.xx.xx.xx/geo to get geo data (ok, yes, there is a daily API limit, but let's assume I could)
- write the resulting information as an array of JSON objects in a new file
- and of course profit from the fact that this will run in parallel and therefore be much faster than doing it sequentially

The first filter is easy as it's returning immediately (here using Bluebird):

```
Promise.each(urls, function(value, index, length) {
  return value.length > 0;
}).then(
  console.log(urls);
);
```

But how can I feed back the result of an asynchronous head request back to the Promise?  Here is another, more complete example of where I'm hitting a wall (see the comments inline):

```
<pre class="prettyprint lang-js">

var Promise = require('bluebird'),
  request = Promise.promisifyAll(require('request'));

var urls = ["", "https://google.com/", "http://www.nonexistent.url"];

var checkLength = function(url) {
    return Promise.resolve(url.length > 0);
}

var checkHead = function(url) {
    return Promise.resolve(
      // ??? seee below for an 'unPromised' function that works on its own
    )
}

var logit = function(value) {
  console.log((urls.length - value.length) + " empty line(s)");
}

Promise
  .filter(urls, checkLength)
  // and here? .filter(urls, checkHead) ? I don't think this would work.
  // and I haven't even look at the map functions yet, although I guess
  // that once I've understood the basic filter, map should be similar.
  .then(logit);

</pre>
```

For the `checkHead` function I planned to modify something like this:

```
var isURLvalid = function(url) {
  request
    .head(url)
    .on('response', function(response) {
      console.log("GOT SUCCESS: " + response);
      callback(response.statusCode < 300);
    })
    .on('error', function(error) {
      console.log("GOT ERROR: " + response);
      callback(false);
    })
};
```

Without wanting to complain, I'm still desperately looking for some good tutorial introductory material that takes the developer who's unfamiliar with Promises by the hand and shows practical implementations of common use cases, cookbook-like. If there is, I'd be glad to get some pointers.

Comment: Not a direct answer to your question, but I frankly don't find Promises to be any kind of useful magic for my spellbook.  I find async.js to be much more intuitive (and better documented to boot).  YMMV

Comment: There are numerous tutorials on Promises, you just need to look for them. Most of them are for "plain" promises (Promise/A+ spec) but if you read and understand those, you'll understand all there is to know about Promises. The syntactic sugar supplied by libraries such as bluebird just make common patterns easier.

Comment: [One good introductory workshop](https://github.com/stevekane/promise-it-wont-hurt). Two quick advices: nodejs includes [native Promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise), don't use extra modules if you don't need the extra features (there is [request-promise](https://www.npmjs.com/package/request-promise), no need to promisify it yourself); don't use Promises for simple synchronous tasks like filtering an array, Array.filter will do just fine.

Comment: @ShanShan the request-promise link seems to be the ticket, or at least mine, as demonstrated by e.sundin below. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The filter and map functions works like the default ones for the JavaScript Array.

I've used request with promises before and there is a specific module just for this called request-promise. It might be more convenient.

I do feel like request-promise module is great to show how Promises are great.

Instead of falling into callback hell where each added request would go deeper you could instead to this with promises

```
rp(login)
.then(function(body) {
    return rp(profile);
})
.then(function(body) {
    return rp(profile_settings);
})
.then(function(body) {
    return rp(logout);
})
.catch(function(err) {
    // the procedure failed
    console.error(err);
});
```

I rewrote your current code to this

```
var Promise = require("bluebird");
var rp = require("request-promise");

var urls = ["", "https://google.com/", "http://www.nonexistent.url"];

Promise
    // checkLength
    .filter(urls, function(url){return url.length > 0})
    .then(function(list) {
        // logit
        console.log((urls.length - list.length) + " empty line(s)");

        // checkHead
        return Promise.filter(list, function(url) {
            // using request-promise and getting full response
            return rp.head({ uri: url, resolveWithFullResponse: true })
                .promise().then(function(response) {
                    // only statusCode 200 is ok
                    return response.statusCode === 200;
                })
                .catch(function(){
                    // all other statuscodes incl. the
                    // errorcodes are considered invalid
                    return false;
                });
        })
    })
    .then(console.log);
```

Comment: @esundin that looks promising (pun intended)! I'll try tonight and will come back. Thanks a lot! :-)

Comment: I'm not sure what best practice is, but I put the 'final' script in a gist here: https://gist.github.com/jfix/823792f4914044380ef0.